I am facing an issue to update the Web Whatsapp Text input field with using DOM methods

This is a screenshot demonstrating my attempt to change content inside a span tag. I am only able to change the text of sent messages, but I cannot change the text in the textarea field. Please help me solve this problem.
Thanks in advance!

To change the value in an <input> or <textarea> element, you need to set its value attribute.
Html:

<input id="my-input" type="text" />

<textarea id="my-textarea"></textarea>

JS:
const input = document.getElementById('my-input')
const textarea = document.getElementById('my-textarea')

input.value = 'Test input value'
textarea.value = 'Test textarea value'



https://www.loom.com/share/73b73f1bd15c48109ebfbf3a4f0a0f2f?sid=3ca28394-c637-47af-8044-1382129245a6
After Watching this video Hope so you will understand what i wanted to achive in Web WhatsApp also. My extension Code working on gmail , GPT and other platforms But not able to overWrite the Data in Web WhatsApp
